# How to store data to database in phonegap

Tags: cordova

I want to store user information in a database.

Is the best way to do this by using jQuery to get data from a mysql table? Is that even possible?

I want to do it efficiently and easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a local database, I recommend checking out the Local Storage APIs for Cordova:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

If this is a remote database, you will probably need to write an API on the server where you're storing the data, and use jQuery to send the data to the server using an XHR.

Comment: What do you mean by write an API on the server? If I wanted to could I write a php script on the server that updates the database with post data submitted by a jquery function?